# Angular 6: Custom Pipe NameSpace is not bound

Tags: angular, pipe, angular-pipe

I'm new to using custom pipes and didn't find any answers to the problem I am having. I am transforming an existing url string, adding a keyword within the string before it was rendered. I've managed to change/return the string to the template, but getting error below;

**customPipe' is not bound less
This inspection checks for unbound namespace prefixes in XML**

```
  <img src={{url | customPipe: url}} default="assets/no_image.png">

export class CustomPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(str: string): any {
    let tn = '_thumbnail';
    let s1 = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("."));
    let s2 = str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf("."));
    let returnS = s2.concat(tn, s1);
    console.log('concatenated string: ', returnS)
    return returnS;
  }

}
```

I can console.log the string and the result is what I'm looking for. Any idea what the error is?

Answer (score 1):

Your pipe has no arguments, you should use it as follows:

```
<img [src]="url | customPipe" default="assets/no_image.png">
```

By the way, if you now the types involved in your pipe operation, avoid the usage of `any` as type

Comment: this did it. Thanks Jota.